# Why does comparing a property to the author.id not work?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

So here is my current code for a currency system. This code works to add the new user information in. Obviously this will keep adding the people that are already in it.

```
if (!currency[message.author.id]) {
            currency.push({id: message.author.id, coins: 0});
        }
```

if I change it to this one, nothing happens. It seems there's something wrong with this comparison and I'm not sure what it is considering it worked for other things I have used.

```
if (!currency[0].id == message.author.id) {
            currency.push({id: message.author.id, coins: 0});
        }
```

This looks right to me as it's getting the id property of the first element and checking if they're the same. When I run the code it just doesn't do anything. No errors and nothing in the json file I'm using to store it. It does this when the array is empty and does it when I have an id property in there.

Is this not possible? I don't like having to set it up using the first way because I'd like to be able to access everyone's currency if needed to add or take away without having to do it one person at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it should be `!==`:

```
if (currency[0].id !== message.author.id) {
            currency.push({id: message.author.id, coins: 0});
}
```

or should be wrapped in brackets:

```
if (!(currency[0].id == message.author.id)) {
            currency.push({id: message.author.id, coins: 0});
}
```

Comment: I wrapped it and it works perfectly. Thank you so much i don't know why I didn't realize that.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you probably want a data structure that's an *object*, not an array, so that you can have arbitrary key-value pairs - have the key be the `message.author.id`.

```
const currency = {};
// ...

const { id } = message.author;
if (!currency[id]) {
  currency[id] = { id, coins: 0 };
} else {
  // this author was already inserted - do something else here, if desired
  // current[id].coins += coinChangeAmount;  // for example
}
```

Your original code sounds like it's misusing an array as an object, and the `currency[0].id == message.author.id` will only check the `[0]`th element of the array, rather than iterating over all possible elements and looking for an ID match.

Comment: See I have that setup for my leveling system as well as another event I had going but I don't like that I can't give everyone coins with 1 command if needed. It will all go by author id and I don't know a way to loop through every one like I could do with a for loop

Comment: It'd be really easy to give everyone coins with an object. `for (const obj of Object.values(currency)) obj.coins++`, for example